# Output multilevel javascript object into an html list

Tags: javascript, html-lists, javascript-objects

I have a large javascript object converted from XML. It has hierarchy, xml attributes (properties defined by an @attributename symbol) and xml values (properties defined by an #text symbol). So the following:

```
<parentnode length="5">
    <childnode length="22" depth="45">This is a child node</childnode>
</parentnode>
```

creates an object that looks like this:

```
parentnode {
    @length: "22"
    childnode {
        @depth: "45",
        @text: "This is a child node"
    }
}
```

and I want to create an HTML list that looks like this:

```
<ul>
    <li data-length="22">parentnode
       <ul>
           <li data-depth="45">childnode: This is a child node</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I've tried various solutions, but none of them work for objects nested in objects with various data types.

Comment: did you check this already? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127554/parse-xml-to-ul it looks like you just need to parse an xml object to an ordered list, don't you?..

Comment: @briosheje Yes, but I'm looking for a different layout. That solution focuses on arrays of urls for a menu system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put together a simple solution. Maybe this will help someone else:

```
function createHtmlList(obj){
    var output = "";
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(k) {
        if (typeof obj[k] == "object" && obj[k] !== null){
            output += "<li>" + htmlSpecialChars(k) + "<ul>";
            output += createHtmlList(obj[k]);
            output += "</ul></li>";
        } else {
            output += "<li>" + k + " : " + obj[k] + "</li>"; 
        }
    });
    return output;
}
```

Comment: @TheCarver my solution is in Javascript.

Comment: My apologies, I commented on the wrong answer!! I couldn't reverse my downvote unless changes were made to your answer, so I just neatened up the formatted code and upvoted you again :/

Comment: I don't have `htmlSpecialChars()`. Ended up using [`entities.encode(k)`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-entities) instead